# Is QMA known to contain Co-NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes, complexity, qma

Is QMA known to contain Co-NP? If not, would Co-NP being contained in QMA have any implications for other complexity classes. (e.g. Causing the polynomial heirachy to collapse.)

Comment: Not yet: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128509/is-qma-known-to-contain-co-np

Comment: I have answered the original question on cs stackexchange. Should this question be closed now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently known. In [my MSc. thesis](https://theses.liacs.nl/pdf/2017-2018-VinkhuijzenLieuwe.pdf), I show that, if it were true, then a consequence would be that $NP^{NP}\subseteq QMA$ (Theorem 21, below). I conjecture that in fact $coNP\subseteq 
 QMA$ implies $PH\subseteq QMA$, but I was not able to prove that.

**Lemma 14.** $NP^{QMA\cap coQMA}\subseteq QMA$.

**Theorem 21.** If $QMA$ contains $co\text-NP$, then $NP^{NP}\subseteq QMA$

*Proof.* If $QMA$ contains $coNP$, then, equivalently, $NP\subseteq coQMA$, so we have $NP\subseteq QMA\cap coQMA$. Plugging this in, we get $NP^{NP}\subseteq NP^{QMA\cap coQMA}\subseteq QMA$ by Lemma 14. $\square$

The thesis contains other consequences, and variations and generalizations of this theorem.